# Composition and Dependency Properties usage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm not sure by correct using of DependencyProperty.AddOwner function. Please, see attached code.
Type Rectangle is only for ilustration. Actually there is used type from third-party library.

```
...
using System.Windows.Shapes;
...

public class CustomShape : DependencyObject
{    
    string id;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public CustomShape(string id)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = 
Rectangle.FillProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomShape));

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return (Brush)rectangle.GetValue(FillProperty); }
        set { rectangle.SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
    }                    
}
```

Comment: Compile it and see.  Debug it and see.  [ask]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what i should see. I used it in simple application and it worked like I want. But I'm not sure if this using of `AddOwner` and `rectangle.GetValue` and `rectangle.SetValue` is correct. And this is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to call set GetValue and SetValue on `rectangle`, or any other member. If `Fill` is supposed to be a property of your CustomShape class, its declaration should look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
   Shape.FillProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomShape));

public Brush Fill
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
}
```

You may however bind the Rectangle's Fill property to the one of your CustomShape:

```
public CustomShape()
{
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty,
            new Binding("Fill") { Source = this });
}
```

Alternatively you may register a PropertyChangedCallback for the Fill property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = Shape.FillProperty.AddOwner(
    typeof(CustomShape),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((CustomShape)o).FillPropertyChanged(e)));

private void FillPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    rectangle.Fill = (Brush)e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The way with binding is better for me, becouse value in `Fill` and `rectangle.Fill` will always be the same. But in callback's example the `rectangle.Fill` could be changed elsewhere and I can not find out from CustomShape class.